# override plugin function in a class not working

Tags: plugins

there is a class "CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller" called in a plugin like that:

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'woocommerce_mstore_init');
    function woocommerce_mstore_init()
    {
        include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "controllers/flutter-order.php";
    }
```

while in that flutter-order.php the code is

```
class CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller extends WC_REST_Orders_Controller
    {
        bla bla bla
        function create_new_order($request)
        {
             bla bla bla
        }

    }
new CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller();
```

in my custom plugin I have tried to do this ( but it's not working at all )

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'hmp_custom_woocommerce_mstore_init', 999);
function hmp_custom_woocommerce_mstore_init(){
if (!class_exists('CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller') ) {
    return;
}
class hmp_CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller extends CUSTOM_WC_REST_Orders_Controller
{
    function create_new_order($request)
    {
        return("test44");
        
}
```

Comment: You can’t replace arbitrary classes in plugins. That’s not even what your plugin does. You’ve just created a new class with a different name. If you want to change the response of a plugin’s class you need to check with its author or documentation whether they have provided a filter to do so.

Comment: I don't want to replace the class, I want to override a function inside that class, and I already did that for other classes, but don't know why this exactly doesn't want to be overriden.

Comment: You could try and post some code that works, so we can see the difference between working code and non-working code. Thanks!